# Allows music playback during recording video like snapchat ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, avcapturesession

First I want to discuss the scenario happening in [snapchat](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/snapchat/id447188370?mt=8).

In snapchat when you start recording video and song is running in background; It allows continue that song while recording video and after you record that video you can also able to hear that song in background.

I am using [SCRecorder](https://github.com/rFlex/SCRecorder) for recording video and capture image with my custom layout . Now in that I want to do just like above scenario but problem is whenever I start recording the video in background song is stopped playing.

SCRecorder is using `AVCaptureSession` for recording video.

So how can I resolve this two problem:

1. Allow background music whiile recording in video using SCRecorder.
2. Record song that is playing in background in video .

Comment: Have you resolved your issue with SCRecorder? I am doing the same and able to play music in background. but my issue is when i open/close app, music stops for a sec and then restart automatically. While i don't want to stop music even for a second.

Comment: no @Surjeet. I am still looking for answer .If you find something please let me know.

Comment: Yes, I done with this and allowed recording and music play in background simultaneously.  but it give me 1 sec pause and restart automatically. If you want same, i can help you.

Comment: yes please add it as an answer here .so it will be helpful to others also and may some one can also resolve the 1 second hold issue. @Surjeet

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is what i used to allow background music play with SCRecorder library.
Hope this help for you too.

Write this code in your **AppDelegate** class within **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**  method -

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord  withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers|AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker|AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:nil];

    [session setActive:YES error:nil];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

After this write below line in **SCRecorder** libaray's '***SCRecorder.m***' file
within **prepare** method **after initialising AVCaptureSession**.

```
session.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = NO;
```

If you are not a SCRecorder library user, then write above line just after initialising AVCaptureSession in your class.

Comment: best answer out-there! works well on iOS10. would like to understand if "[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];" and why remote control events are important.

Comment: .allowBluetoothA2DP is better than .allowBluetooth. if set both, then Hands-Free Profile (HFP)

Comment: .allowBluetoothA2DP ->  Advanced Audio Distribution Profile (A2DP)
.allowBluetooth -> Hands-Free Profile (HFP)
.allowBluetoothA2DP is better than .allowBluetooth. if set both, then Hands-Free ports will be given a higher priority for routing.

Comment: I used the same method provided above. It allow background music play but now my camera freezes. it is full black screen now.

Comment: @AmanGupta Make sure, you haven't override AudioSession again with other config.

Comment: I checked and update the code and it is worked now. Thanks!

Comment: This causes a short stutter for the music when opening/closing the app. Is there a way to delay audio session activation (and the short stutter) to only run "on-demand", aka when starting the recording? I have created a question on SO here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67807394/5281431

Comment: To use this on-demand, just call function with above lines when required instead of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.