# Recording a Video without stopping sound/music from device

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation

I am working with Swift's AVFoundation to capture a video in iOS. But when I play a song using Apple Music/Spotify then click the record button of my app, it pauses/stops the music then records the video. How do I prevent that from happening?

Here's my code:

```
@IBAction func record_video(sender: AnyObject) {
        var initialOutputURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "")

        do
        {
            initialOutputURL = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true).URLByAppendingPathComponent("output").URLByAppendingPathExtension("mov")
        }catch
        {
            print(error)
        }
        if !isRecording
        {

            isRecording = true
            if let outputs = captureSession.outputs as? [AVCaptureOutput] {
                for output in outputs {
                    captureSession.removeOutput(output)
                }
            }

            do
            {
                try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
            }
            catch
            {
                print("Can't Set Audio Session Category: \(error)")
            }
            AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.MixWithOthers

            do
            {
                try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeVideoRecording)
            }
            catch
            {
                print("Can't Set Audio Session Mode: \(error)")
            }
            // Start Session
            do
            {
                try audioSession.setActive(true)
            }
            catch
            {
                print("Can't Start Audio Session: \(error)")
            }


            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.Repeat, .Autoreverse, .AllowUserInteraction], animations: { () -> Void in
                self.record.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75, 0.75)
                }, completion: nil)

            let audioInputDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)
            do
            {
                let audioInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioInputDevice)

                // Add Audio Input
                if captureSession.canAddInput(audioInput)
                {
                    //captureSession.addInput(audioInput)
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog("Can't Add Audio Input")
                }

            let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput
            do
            {
                videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)

                // Add Video Input
                if captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput)
                {
                    captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog("ERROR: Can't add video input")
                }
            }
            catch let error
            {
                NSLog("ERROR: Getting input device: \(error)")
            }
            videoFileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
            captureSession.addOutput(videoFileOutput)
            captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh
            captureSession.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = false

            videoFileOutput?.startRecordingToOutputFileURL(initialOutputURL, recordingDelegate: self)


            }
            catch let error
            {
                NSLog("Error Getting Input Device: \(error)")
            }

        }
        else
        {
            isRecording = false

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: [], animations: { () -> Void in
                self.record.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)
                }, completion: nil)
            record.layer.removeAllAnimations()
            videoFileOutput?.stopRecording()
        }



    }
```

Notice that I commented out `captureSession.addInput(audioInput)`. If I remove that code, the app is able to record the video, it doesn't pause/stop the music but the video output has no sound. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue on my own. The line: `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.MixWithOthers` doesn't do anything. I moved it to the options:
`try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, withOptions: [AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.MixWithOthers])`

It worked!

Comment: where did you declare audioSession in your code?

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to the answer of this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715597/allows-music-playback-during-recording-video-like-snapchat-ios/32416013#32416013)

I have implemented same feature using SCRecorder Library, but can be achieve with AVCaptureSession as well.

Comment: I am getting `Can't Set Audio Session Mode: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "(null)"' and `Can't add video input` after adding this: `self.captureSession.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = false;`

Answer (score 1):

here is what worked for me in swift, it is essentially the same thing as jayson's answer but for swift.

add this code in  your

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?){


        add your laucher code
       let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        // Set the audio session category, mode, and options.
        try audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord,  options: [.mixWithOthers,.defaultToSpeaker,.allowBluetooth])
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
    } catch {
        print("Failed to set audio session category.")
    }
  }
```

then in the file where your set up your capturesession

```
   captureSession.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = false
```

essentially mixwithother works as it says in the doc "option that indicates whether audio from this session mixes with audio from active sessions in other audio apps"  (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/categoryoptions) and default to speakers allows the music to come out louder when working with the mix with others options.

Comment: This helps in playing music in background while camera open. Can you let me know how to record the background music and mic while recording video? 
Currently, Mic will only record when no background music is playing. If background music is playing then it didn't record anything.